# How to get test Layar for Testing iphone layar app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, augmented-reality, layar

i have integrated layar framework in iphone project, but now i want to test app with some layars. But app requires layar name, consumer key and secret key. Is there any source from which i get layars for free to test. And how can i get their layar name, consumer key and secret key for those free testing layar ??

Comment: i do not want to create my layar, instead i want to test on available public free layars.!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a layer in [Layar Create](https://www.layar.com/publishing/#layers). At this point you will add your layar name, consumer key and secret key. Once this is done, you have to add your point of interest in your server. Layar gives you an SQL statement and PHP files to manage the point of interests inside your Layar and your own app. If you wanted to publish your app with the layar, first you have to publish your layar inside the Layar site.

You can read this documentation and try this code [link](http://www.layar.com/documentation/browser/howtos/geolocation-layer/).

It is very easy to have Layar in your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Try scanning [this image](http://static511.layar.com.s3.amazonaws.com/media/content_media/257/layar-logo-usage.png) from the 'LAYAR' home page.
If you are signed up on 'LAYAR', you can easily create some test pages for a new campaign [here](https://www.layar.com/creator/)
helps test all options and have a clear visual.